# Proof by Contradiction: Opposite Angles of a Parallelogram

Tags: proof-writing

Prove the following statement by contradiction: "the opposite angles of a parallelogram are equal."

Proofs by contradiction involving words like this are super confusing to me as I just generally don't know where to start? Obviously the very first step is to assume (in this case) that "the opposites angles of a parallelogram are **not** equal," but from there I have no clue. How do I express this in a way that can be worked out?

Comment: Why to prove from contradiction?  you can prove it like https://www.teachoo.com/4277/1043/Theorem-8.4---Class-9---In-a-parallelogram--opposite-angles-are-equal/category/Theorems/

Comment: that's what the unit is, so unfortunately I have to do it by contradiction.